# Google Feed API skipping articles?

Tags: javascript, api, rss, google-feed-api

With our without an API Key, the google feed api appears to be skipping some of the latest articles in the RSS queried.

Even the default example from https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide?csw=1 appears to be skipping some articles whatever feed I use, see example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbxxwE

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("feeds", "1");

function initialize() {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://fastpshb.appspot.com/feed/1/fastpshb"); 
  feed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
      var container = document.getElementById("feed");
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
        container.appendChild(div);
      }
    }
  });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

</script>
```

I'm specifically using this RSS, http://blog.ncb.org.uk/syndication.axd and the first 2 articles are not appearing either.

Is there anyone else using the API and experiencing the same issue? Where should we go from here? Is there some sort of support for the Feed API?

Cheers,
P.

Comment: Maybe give a shot at other solutions like [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google [caches the results](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-ajax-search-api/fHpY633JVuQ/eKGAHqYegjMJ) and it may take up to an hour for it to refresh. That is why the latest articles wont show immediately.

[Here was someone having similar issues](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-ajax-search-api/iOaYakGRIiY/O_i_h_2inqYJ) of the feed not getting updated. It could be that maintaining the Feed API is not a high priority to Google any more. [Yahoo Pipes](https://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) or [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com/) could be good alternatives.